# Django: append a count of manytomany object instances and then retrieve it in template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, append, many-to-many

Okay, so I'm sure i'm making a simple error here but I'm at a loss as to what it might be at this point or where to even begin to find the cause of this failing...

I have 5 models, set up like so:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=2000, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key

class Entries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=200)
    updated = models.DateTimeField("Last Updated", auto_now=True)
    key_list = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, blank=True, verbose_name="Keywords")
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True    

class Employee(Entries):
    uid= models.SlugField("UserID", max_length=6, unique=True, blank=True)
    manager = models.SlugField("Manager's UserID", max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Vendor(Entries):
    company = models.CharField("Vendor Company", max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField("Vendor's Company Email Address", max_length=254, unique=True)
    vend_man_name = models.CharField("Manager's Name", max_length=200)
    vend_man_email = models.EmailField("Manager's Email Address", max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Application(Entries):
    app_url = models.URLField("Application URL", max_length=800, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Machine(Entries):
    address = models.CharField("Machine Address", max_length=800, unique=True)
    phys_loc = models.TextField("Physical Location", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and my templatetag to display the data is thus:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('Labswho/key_cloud.html')
def key_cloud(keys_selected=''):
    key_list = Keyword.objects.all()
    for entry in key_list:
        counter = Keyword.objects.filter(employee__key_list__key__contains=entry).distinct().count()
        counter += Keyword.objects.filter(vendor__key_list__key__contains=entry).distinct().count()
        counter += Keyword.objects.filter(application__key_list__key__contains=entry).distinct().count()
        counter += Keyword.objects.filter(machine__key_list__key__contains=entry).distinct().count()
        entry.append({'counter': counter})
    context = {'key_list': key_list}
    return context
```

but it keeps throwing me errors.

What I want it to do is to grab a count of the instances of each keyword on each model, add those instances together, and then give me a number I can reference in the template. My end goal is that I can use that number to set the font size so that keywords used more frequently will be visibly larger then ones used less frequently. I think what I want is for it to set a dictionary within each entry of my key_list, which i can then call for that number in the template when setting the font size. Not sure if i'm over-complicating this or how to fix it at this point so that it actually works...

(This is using Python 3.5 & Django 1.10)

Comment: Please add the error message(s) including Traceback to your question.

Comment: So all you want is the count and not the references to those items, right?

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting an error by trying to append to the entry object instead of assigning the value counter to it `entry.counter = counter`

There are other problems, too. The keys_selected argument is unused. Even with that changed, this is not a good way to add counts to entries. I'm not exactly sure what your goal is for this template tag based on its current logic, but you should at least look into using Q objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: @KlausD. 'Keyword' object has no attribute 'append' is the error I am getting

Comment: @AaronHampton see, I knew it would be something stupid and simple I was missing...entry.counter = counter does in fact do exactly what I need. thank you. I'm not sure how I would use a q object here to do this better, care to expand on that? I am under the impression that since i'm referenceing multiple models, I would need to do it this way. All the examples in the documentation you linked seem to point that way, but if you know a better way I'm all ears. keys_selected is something i'll be using later for the next part of this now that I have the rest working, I didn't meant to include it.